# Select from three table

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a question about selecting data from three tables
the first table is like that:`Timetable`

```
ClassID   teacherID   assistantID    
1           1            2
0                    
2            3            4
```

` 0 is a break time, so No assistants and teachers

`Class` table:

```
classID     classname    
0            Break    
1            MATH    
2            ART
```

`teacher` table

```
teacherID     teacherName    
1               Tom    
2               Lily    
3               Rose    
4               Nile
```

I want to produce a table like this
`Timetables`:

```
ClassName      TeacherName     AssistantName    
Math            Tom            Liky    
Break                  
Art             Rose            Nile
```

Comment: could you format the tables more readable?

Answer (score 1):

Join the `teacher` table twice with different alias names

```
select c.className, teach.teacherName, assist.teacherName as assistantName
from Timetable t
join class c on c.classID = t.classID 
left join teacher teach on teach.teacherID = t.teacherID 
left join teacher assist on assist.teacherID = t.assistantID
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the timetable break only have a ID and no teacher and assistant.

Comment: Did you test the query?

Comment: yes, It only produce table having math and art. the reason is that when in break, there are no teachers. However,I do not know how to do

Comment: I changed the `join` into a `left join`. Try again.

Comment: Yeeeees, It works. many Thanks, Maybe I need to revise database design again although already revised.....

Comment: You should. `break` is not really a class. If you have a question about the design then ask a new question and explain what you try to do and add your current design and problems you have with it.